# mpirun binding to l3cache or none used with OMP_PLACES and OMP_PROC_BIND

Tags: multithreading, parallel-processing, mpi, openmp, cpu

I wish to run my application in 32 MPI processes each spanning 8 OpenMP threads. I am benchmarking different options for core binding

I tested first

```
export OMP_NUM_THREADS=8
mpirun --bind-to l3cache --use-hwthread-cpus -np 32 myapp_mpi apprun -s benchdata.tpr -v -noconfout -g res.txt
```

I don't know exactly how the processes and threads are distributed then. Is there a rule ?

Then I set

```
export OMP_PLACES=”thread(8)”
export OMP_PROC_BIND=true
```

I don't if I should then use `mpirun` binding to `none`, because the two previous OpenMP settings control the binding anyway or if I should `--bind-to l3cache` (one bloc of l3cache "has" 8 cores).

```
mpirun --bind-to l3cache --use-hwthread-cpus -np 32 myapp_mpi apprun -s benchData.tpr -v -noconfout -g res.txt
```

What other strategies do you use for doing an efficient processes and threads binding ?

Comment: I wouldn't overdo it. If you L3 has 8 cores then the MPI specification alone might already be enough. Run a bunch of test and time them. I'm guessing that your OpenMP threads only "see" the cores of the MPI process, so `OMP_PROC_BIND=true` maybe enough to keep the threads from wandering. Unless of course your application is dynamic (or you use dynamic scheduling; notice that you have said nothing about your application? That is actually important....) and you actually want them to be able to move about.

Comment: That is a two steps tango: bind each MPI task to a set of 8 cores, and then have the OpenMP runtime bind the threads (within the set of 8 cores). Your mpirun command looks good, and using `OMP_PROC_BIND=true` alone should do the trick.

Comment: Thanks, side question for you to elaborate an answer to all, example of scientific computing apps, where precise core pinning deliver significantly better perf

Comment: If you are unsure of the mapping you can diplay the mapping using `OMP_DISPLAY_ENV=VERBOSE` and `KMP_AFFINITY=verbose`. Besides this, you can use the great `hw-loc` tool to control and track affinity issues. Regarding the hardware, using `numactl` may also help (typically on NUMA systems).